# Regex match 1 or 2 digits without error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern?

Tags: regex

How to capture 1 or 2 digits in a regex?

**Text**

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = 1/1/g1, Office to DMZ
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10 = 1/1/g10, Office to DMZ
```

**Regex**

This works for [1 digit](http://regexr.com/5pr2m) only. ie. 1/1/g1 but does not work for 2 digits. ie. 1/1/1g10.

```
(?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d = ).*)
```

This works for [2 digits](http://regexr.com/5pr2p) in the regex tester but not in python3 in centos.

```
(?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d|\d = ).*)
```

I get the following error:

**re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern**

Comment: your regex mask has a problem is that capture not for all case, `.*` is bad.

Comment: try this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y1IgVm/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't make a lookbehind non-fixed width, but you can group two lookbehinds with an or condition:

```
(?:(?<=ifDescr\.\d = )|(?<=ifDescr\.\d\d = ))(?P<ifDescr>.*)
```

- `(?:...)` a non-capture group
- `(?<=ifDescr\.\d = )` lookbehind, match `ifDescr.` with one digit
- `|` or
- `(?<=ifDescr\.\d\d = )` lookbehind, match `ifDescr.` with two digits
- `(?P<ifDescr>.*)` match whatever after it, and set a group back reference called `ifDescr`

check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/cq7PS1/1/)

---

But this works for limited combinations. If you're not sure how many digits there are, you should use group captures, and then get the result from group `ifDescr`

```
(?:ifDescr\.\d+ = )(?P<ifDescr>.*)
```